# Obtaining a error when running custom Python script

Tags: python, syntax-error

Bit of background,

I am a wet lab researcher with minimal experience in a python environment. I've read a couple of books on it because I have been working with a lot of scripts lately for my data analysis, but all these scripts are made by other people and I just tend to need to alter a couple of lines here and there to get it to work for me. However, i've run into a problem I can't seem to fix and I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makingIntronAnnotation.py", line 36, in <module>
   exonNb = int(annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'gene_type `"transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene'`
```

For those of you that are biologically oriented I am essentially trying to create an intron annotation file complementary to the exons file I have created using grep in the exonAnnotation.gtf file from a gencode annotation file (version 23).

Here is the entirety of the script:

```
import sys


#  parsedInGTFfile (containing only exons) and obtained as follows: grep $'\texon\t' input.gtf > exonAnnotation.gtf
inGTF=open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
outGTF=open(sys.argv[2], 'w')

prevGeneID = ""
prevTrxID = ""
prevStart = 0
prevEnd   = 0
prevExonNb = 0
geneList = []
geneIDList = []

for line in inGTF:
    SL = line.rstrip().split("\t")
    annot = SL[8].split("; ")
    geneID = annot[0]
    trxID = annot[1]
    geneName = annot[3]
    exonNb = int(annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))
    strand = SL[6]
    start = SL[3]
    end = SL[4]

    if geneID==prevGeneID and trxID==prevTrxID and exonNb == (prevExonNb + 1):
        if strand == '+':
            newEnd = int(start) - 1
            newStart = int(prevEnd) + 1

        if strand == '-':
            newEnd = int(prevStart) -1
            newStart = int(end) + 1

        newGeneID = geneID.rstrip('"')+'.Intron"'
        newTrxID = trxID.rstrip('"')+'.Intron"'

        if geneList.count(geneName) > 1:
            geneName = geneName.rstrip('"')+'.'+str(geneList.count(geneName))+'"'

        newGeneName = geneName.rstrip('"')+'.Intron"'
        intron = 'intron_number "'+ str(prevExonNb) + '"'
        outGTF.write(SL[0]+"\tintronAnnotation\texon\t"+str(newStart)+"\t"+str(newEnd)+"\t.\t"+strand+"\t.\t"+newGeneID+"; "+newTrxID+"; "+intron+"; "+newGeneName+";\n")


    elif geneID==prevGeneID and trxID!=prevTrxID:
        pass
    else:
        if geneID not in geneIDList:
            geneList.append(geneName)
            geneIDList.append(geneID)

    prevStart = int(start)
    prevGeneID = geneID
    prevEnd = int(end)
    prevTrxID = trxID
    prevExonNb = exonNb

inGTF.close()
outGTF.close()
```

The file contains the following type of information, there are 9 columns with the 9th column not being tab delimited but with a semicolon (I am sorry that it looks so messy, but this is essentially what I stare at all day and there is really no way for me to make it easier to read, but i'm sure you all probably stare at worsely cluttered terminal screens).

```
chr1    HAVANA  exon    11869   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00002234944.1"; level 2; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12613   12721   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00003582793.1"; level 2; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    13221   14409   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000456328.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "processed_transcript"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-002"; exon_number 3; exon_id "ENSE00002312635.1"; level 2; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000362751.1";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12010   12057   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 1; exon_id "ENSE00001948541.1"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "NA"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
chr1    HAVANA  exon    12179   12227   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000223972.5"; transcript_id "ENST00000450305.2"; gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; gene_status "KNOWN"; gene_name "DDX11L1"; transcript_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene"; transcript_status "KNOWN"; transcript_name "DDX11L1-001"; exon_number 2; exon_id "ENSE00001671638.2"; level 2; ont "PGO:0000005"; ont "PGO:0000019"; tag "basic"; transcript_support_level "NA"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000000961.2"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000002844.2";
```

I'd appreciate any advice, even if it's not a complete answer (though that would be preferable lol).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First piece of advice: It sounds like you're doing all your work in a terminal (using vim or emacs). While this is helpful, what you would find maybe even more helpful is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). This gives you much more flexibility with writing and running your code. If you don't already have one, I would suggest installing [sublime2](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which is a popular, minimalist ide.

Comment: Will definitely look into this. I don't write code very often, but for my recent projects i've been looking into NGS data a lot and somehow I am the only computer literate person in my lab so I have had to slowly adapt. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: You're posted data wont parse since it is not reproduced with the tabs in place so it is difficult to find the error - the line 'for line in inGTF:' is reading the data but the next line can't split what you posted - this makes it hard to help debug

Comment: What can I do to give you guys the data you would require to help debug this?

Comment: In the best interest for you and everyone else, I would suggest not sharing your data. Reasons. 1.) You shouldn't be giving your employers data out to anyone and I'm sure your managers would agree with that. 2.) This is about you learning how to better solve these issues in the future. This is why SO is here, to help you learn. SO isn't here to solve your problems for you which is what would happen if you posted the data. Please take a look at my answer and  I'll walk you through on how to solve this problem on your own!

Comment: @Austin A I really appreciate you making sure I'm not sharing data that would get me into trouble. However this data is actually publicly available at the Gencode project website, there's nothing self generated here. And the script can be gotten by contacting the authors of a paper I am attempting to replicate, so no harm there. But thank you! I've managed to solve the problem using one of the other answers. I knew what the script wanted, I just had no idea where to put the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is a result of trying to convert a string to an int here.

Let's take a look at the script to figure out what went wrong.

`SL = line.rstrip().split("\t")`

- Splits your input file into a list, delimited by tab characters.

`annot = SL[8].split("; ")`

- This splits the last item in the list you just created into a list of the values, delimited by semicolons.

`exonNb = int(annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))`

- Attempts to convert an item in that `annot` list to an integer.

My guess is that the input file has changed format, or the script was written incorrectly. It *looks* like you want index 8 (column 9). So just change the index to 8 like so:

`exonNb = int(annot[8].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to say in some of the comments I was leaving to other answers. I knew what the script wanted, I just had no idea how to give it the information. Thank you so much. This worked. I went ahead and chose your comment as the answer.

Comment: @System Awesome, glad it worked! Happy to help and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
exonNb = int(annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))
```

you are trying to take the int() of a string. Depending on the string, this could work - doesn't seem to be the case here as annot[2] contains no numbers.

EDIT: The problem is that

```
SL = line.rstrip().split("\t")
```

returns a list with one entry (as the string, apparently, contains no tabs).

Comment: This is correct. The int I am trying to take is the exon_number which is found in column 9 under "exon_number 1" for instance. It seems that what it is picking up is the "gene_type "transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene" portion of the column which is obviously not an int. I just don't know exactly how to separate out the 9th column using something like awk.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line below is giving you your problem, like you've already seen.

```
exonNb = int(annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "'))
```

The error you're getting is basically saying, "Hey, that thing you want to convert to an integer? It isn't an integer so sorry." To trouble shoot this, go ahead and add the lines I wrote below, above the line that's throwing the error.

```
exonNB_val = annot[2].rstrip('"').lstrip('exon_number "')
print(type(exonNB_val))
print(exonNB_val)
```

This will print the type of object that you're trying to convert to an integer along with that actual value of the object.

Go ahead and include this in a comment when you get it.

Comment: I've added the code to the line directly below the area, however because the script stops at the exonNB = int error, the print function does not print out anything when it's run.

Comment: I said **above** the problem line. No worries though, I changed wording to be less confusing.

Comment: However, I have some sort of idea of what is happening. It is trying to use the exon_number which IS an int and can be found in the 9th column, but it is taking the "gene_type `"transcribed_unprocessed_pseudogene'`" object instead which can also be found on the 9th column but is a string. EDIT: I included it above and below the script, this is what happens when I include it above: NameError: name 'exonNB' is not defined

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my code. Try it now. You'll see I removed the `int()` command which is what's breaking your code. My bad.

Comment: No worries, one of the other answers seems to have gotten the script to work. I knew what the script wanted, I just really wasn't sure what parameter had to be tweaked to give it that data. The answer described where the edit had to happen to do that. Thank you for the help!